# Visualforce - Jquery initialise

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery to handle the checkbox event to enable and disable the fields in visualforce page. Now i want to disable the fields by default when the edit page is loaded. How can i acheive this by using jquery?

I'm using the below code snippet to disable the field:

```
jQuery( 'input[id$=prodjan_c]' ).prop('disabled', true);
```

How can i default the field as disabled one?

Comment: Do you want to disable single field or are there multiple fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a page loads jQuery will  run the ready function if it is defined and do what you need to.

It would look something like:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  //To disable a single field like you had in your question
  jQuery( 'input[id$=prodjan_c]' ).prop('disabled', true); 

});
```

If you want multiple filed you will either have to select using a class or use the `.each()` function to cycle through and set the value.

The main point is the `.ready()` function.

Comment: Thkx Eric. I worked. Strange through i had the same code earlier but didnt work, perhaps i think i would have not completed the syntax.....thks again.